# Flow entries for traffic monitoring in SDN

Tags: monitoring, traffic, sdn

I'm trying to install flow entries for traffic monitoring in SDN. I wonder if I can set the action as "continue indexing the flow table"? Here is one scenario:

A layer 2 switch with one existing flow entry: "match:dst_mac=00:01, action:outport=1, priority=1", I want to monitor network traffic with src_mac=00:02. Now I'm trying to add an high-priority flow entry "match:src_mac=00:02, action:continue_indexing, priority=2". How can I write the action field? I can't find any similar actions in OpenFlow 1.3.0.

Thanks for your answering!

Comment: What do you mean by continue indexing?

Answer (score 0):

You can either leverage multiple tables for pipeline matching, or
output the packets to the controller first and then inject those packets containing action "Table" back to the tables.

Comment: Currently my OF switch only support a single flow table. Is there any ways to monitor traffic under single flow table scenario?

Comment: As I said, you can output packets with "src_mac=00:02" to the controller.

Comment: You need to differentiate the monitoring and forwarding entries first by taking an unused field for distinction.
As I said, output packets with "src_mac=00:02" to the controller. Then, controller modifies that unused field and packet_out them, which contains action "TABLE", to the OF switch. Now, the packets can match "dst_mac=00:01" to conduct normal forwarding.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!